# ID Text not displaying inside h4 tag

Tags: jquery, html

In my modal header I have a h4 tag with an id. The id is pulling and displaying a saved variable. But when I try to span another id inside of the h tag the span items are not displaying. I want all of the text on the same line.

```
<h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="category">
    <span id="subcategory"></span>
    <span> Test Span</span>
</h4>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".open-details-modal").click(function() {
$('.modal .modal-dialog').css({width: '70%',
                               height: '70%'
                               });
 $('.modal .modal-dialog').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
$("#category").text($(this).attr('data-id-sub-category'));
$("#subcategory").text($(this).attr('data-id-vendor'));
  $("#detailsModal").modal("show");

});
});
```

Comment: Can you show us some JS code?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little better.

Comment: The span id's text is not displaying. Only the H4 text is displaying. The 'id' is referencing a variable.

Comment: can you post your js

Comment: did u try to console out $(this).attr('data-id-vendor') to check if you are getting any data ???

Comment: Yes that works anywhere else but inside the h tags specifically they do not work.

Comment: It shoild work any where .. can you check the css for the span inside h4 in console

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
$("#category").text($(this).attr('data-id-sub-category'));
```

is clearing out the two spans inside of the header.
To fix that it really depends on where exactly you want to put the content inside `#category`, for instance, if you want it to be at the beginning, do

```
$("#category").prepend($(this).attr('data-id-sub-category'));
```

at the end

```
$("#category").append($(this).attr('data-id-sub-category'));
```

or in the bottom span

```
$("#category span:not(#subcategory)").text($(this).attr('data-id-sub-category'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JQuery selector` and `find`the element first

```
var span = $("#category").find("#subcategory");
$(span).text($(this).attr('data-id-vendor'));
```